# How to exchange two keys on the keyboard (El Capitan)

Tags: keyboard, macos

I am currently using a German keyboard on El Capitan. I want to change the keymap for y and z. I have searched relevant information on Google, but the information which I have found so far is so old that I could not apply them.

I also tried to use the following `.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode  52 = z Z z Z leftarrow yen leftarrow
keycode  29 = y Y y Y guillemotright U203A guillemotright
```

But this does not work.

Comment: So you want to have a keyboard layout which is German except that it is QWERTY instead of the normal QWERTZ?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the (free) program [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele).

1. Create a new keyboard layout based on your current one (File -> New From Current Source).
2. On the graphical interface click on the key to which you want to assign a different value, then  provide the intended output:

   [image: Ukulele keyboard layout editor]
3. Save the new layout as a `.keylayout` file to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`<sup>*</sup>.

   Log off, log on.
4. Open System Preferences and select the new layout in Input Sources -> + -> Others -> your_layout_name.

---

<sup>*</sup> You can also save the file in your user's `Library` folder instead of the system one, but then if you lock the machine (i.e. switch to the lock screen), the keyboard layout might change at each unlock.